# Add text to an image and store - Flutter

Tags: image, flutter

Good day ,I am generating certificates and for this I have a template where I must write user data, for the moment I am creating the certificates in pdf format, but the ideal would be to use images or convert those pdf to image since it is easier for the user to handle images, I have not found any library capable of writing in images that works correctly.

At the moment I am trying to use Image. https://pub.dev/packages/image.

I have the following code, but it fails to add a text fragment in the image.

```
 imagecert = await ManagerDB().getcertificate(certificatetemplate); //imagecert is uint8list
    if (imagecert != null) {

      mg.Image ima = mg.Image.fromBytes(300, 200, List.from(imagecert)); Image works with list<int>
      mg.Image imag = mg.drawString(ima, mg.arial_14, 0, 0, 'Hello World'); //here the code does not work
      List<int> data = mg.encodePng(imag);
      Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(data);
      setState(() {});
      return bytes;
    } else {
      print("Enlace no encontrado");
    }
```

I don't know if there is a simpler solution to write text in an image. It is required to store those images.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can put image inside widget and add to that widget text
and converted to image using globalKey (don't forget to pass globalKey to key of that sepecific widget )

```dart
  Future<Uint8List> _convertWidgetToImage(GlobalKey globalKey) async {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
      ByteData byteData =
       (await (image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)))!;
      Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return pngBytes;
 }
```